# Testing hypothesis in 0-1 loss function

Tags: hypothesis-testing, expected-value, loss-functions, decision-theory

Let's say we are testing $H_0=\theta\in\Theta$ vs $H_1=\theta\in\Theta_1$. Set the 0-1 loss function as $l(\theta,a)=I(r(\theta)\neq a)$ where $a\in\{0,1\}$ and $r(\theta)=I(\theta \in \Theta_1)$. I was able to derive the following expressions from these for $\theta, \theta'\in \Theta$ and $\delta(X)$ as decision rule:
$$E_\theta[l(\theta,\delta(X))]=E_\theta[l(r(\theta)\neq\delta(X))]=P_\theta(r(\theta)\neq\delta(X))$$
$$E_\theta[l(\theta',\delta(X))]=E_\theta[l(r(\theta')\neq\delta(X))]=P_\theta(r(\theta')\neq\delta(X))$$
A part that I am struggling with is on how to conclude that $P_\theta(r(\theta')\neq\delta(X))=P_{\theta'}(r(\theta)\neq\delta(X))$. It is not clear for me why this is even true.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What is $P'$ in your ultimate formula?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just edited it. It was supposed to be $P_{\theta'}$. @ChristophHanck